# Instagram redirect issue while authentication in android

Tags: android, authentication, instagram, redirect, instagram-api

I am using Instagram authentication in my android app. I have registered app on [Instagram Developer Console](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) and retrieved Client Id and Client Secret and also added Redirect Url. (*Right now it's in Sandbox mode only*).

Also why it's asking for Security code every time?

I am getting redirect back to app issue while user authentication. below are two case.

- **First Time**

When i click on "Login with Instagram" button, it's loading login screen and after adding Sandbox user credentials, when i press on Login, It's redirecting me on the screen to send security code on Email or Mobile. By choosing any of them i am getting Code and after entering valid code, it's redirecting me on **Instagram Website Dashboard** instead of **send back to the mobile app**. In this case, **it should ask for authorize and redirect me back to my app**.

- **Second Time**

Now if i close app and open again and if i press on "Login with Instagram" button from my Login screen, it's loading login screen and after entering valid credentials it's asking for authorize user for the app. This time it's working fine.

So the issue is if i fresh install app and try to login with Instagram then it's asking for Security code and redirecting me to Instagram website. Second time it's working fine.

I also did many google research as well as code debug for both case but all the time i am getting same urls.

Comment: have you got something workaround till now?